# Getting value from cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I recently started studying PL/SQL and I found myself with this problem. I have a cursor that has the data for a specific person selected via code from another table. I'm fetching all the months with the salary of that person and outputting them. Now I need to make an avg() of all of the salaries. How do I do that ? Can I get only that column from the cursor. I could have counted the rows and divided the total sum of the salaries on that count and I can make another select but is there any faster way ?

Comment: Cursors are generally not the fastest way to do almost anything.  But you can calculate the sum and count yourself in PLSQL and then do the division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need cursor to get average salary as single value. You need to use aggregate functions. And even if you needed a cursor to, lets say, return data to calling code, you still use aggregate function to calculate averages and return cursor of that.

This is just an example

```
Declare
    v_avgSal employees.salary%TYPE;
Begin    
    SELECT AVG(salary) into v_avgSal 
    FROM employees
    WHERE employee_id = 10 And 
          (payDate >= To_Date('01012015', 'MMDDYYYY') AND payDate < To_Date('01012016', 'MMDDYYYY'));
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(v_avgSal);
End;
```